# selecting a default value in a select box from a service

Tags: angular

I have a class and that has a service called filter service that is injected into the class. I am using this service to create a select box and list all the options. I am calling ngOnInit method to call the 
filter.getAccountTypes() method so that the service has the data to populate the dropdowns.

```
 export class ActionsAddComponent {
     constructor(public filter: FilterCollection, public _form: FormBuilder) {
    this.actionForm = this._form.group({
            AccountId: ['', Validators.required],
            Type: ['', Validators.required]
           });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filter.getAccountTypes();
  }
```

In the view i have the following code

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="accountType"> 
        <option *ngFor="#typ of filter.AccountTypes;#i = index" selected="selected" [value]="typ.Id">{{typ.Name}}</option> 
      </select>
```

since the filter.AccountTypes is loaded inside the service i am not able to set the default value of ngModel as the first row. Is there any easy fix for this. So that i can make the first row selected and still have ngmodel.

```
export class FilterCollection {
public AccountTypes;
 getAccountTypes() {
        this.orgId = this._localstore.get('orgId');
        this._http.get('Organisations/' + this.orgId + '/AccountTypes')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.AccountTypes = [];
                for (var x of res.Data)
                    this.AccountTypes.push(new AccountTypesModel(x));
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```ts
    <option *ngFor="let typ of filter.AccountTypes;let i = index; let first=first" [attr.selected]="first ? 'selected' : null" [value]="typ.Id">{{typ.Name}}</option> 

export class FilterCollection {
public AccountTypes;
 getAccountTypes() {
        this.orgId = this._localstore.get('orgId');
        this._http.get('Organisations/' + this.orgId + '/AccountTypes')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map(res => {
                this.AccountTypes = [];
                for (var x of res.Data)
                    this.AccountTypes.push(new AccountTypesModel(x));
            });
    }
}
```

```ts
export class ActionsAddComponent {
     constructor(public filter: FilterCollection, public _form: FormBuilder) {
    this.actionForm = this._form.group({
            AccountId: ['', Validators.required],
            Type: ['', Validators.required]
           });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filter.getAccountTypes().toPromise().then(val => this.accountType = this.filter.AccountTypes[0] ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya that is something that would work if i was able to get the data in the component that is using the service. Right now the data is present in the service and the component does not get the data. so i can't set the default value.

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't tried this myself yet though.

Comment: i got the idea, i was able to get the first row selected. The model only updates on a change event. Is it possible to set model as the default value

Comment: That was my original suggestion. If you set the model to the new value, the select should be updated to this value.

Comment: I have added my service also in my question. 
setting model would be ideal, But in my case i am not sure when the service will get its value from the api and if at all i get this how do i pass it to the component to set model, which event would i use.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the index of the element in the loop to set the value of the `selected` attribute. Don't foget to set `null` if it's not the first element to remove the `selected` attribute from the `option` tag.

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="accountType"> 
  <option *ngFor="#typ of filter.AccountTypes;#i = index" 
     [selected]="i===1 ? 'selected': null"
     [value]="typ.Id">{{typ.Name}}</option> 
</select>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9AzoSzWU0DTFa5chF2SR?p=preview

Comment: its working, but the only thing that does not update is ngModel,ngmodel would still have the initial value is it possible to set the default selected value as ngModel, Now it happens only on a change event.

Comment: So why don't you leverage ngModel to initialize the selected element in the select. I mean set the value of `accountType`. Automatically the right / corresponding option will be selected...